# How to provision Azure Iot Device via another device which has Iot Edge Runtime?

Tags: azure, iot, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-edge, azure-iot-dps

Achieved ->

1. Provisioned Iot Device using Iot SDK directly with Device Provisioning Service
2. Provisioned Iot Edge Device using configurations with Device Provisioning Service

Expected ->
Provision all Iot Device via Iot Edge device which means Iot Device cannot directly provision with Device Provisioning service, it should be or via Iot Edge Device which should Provision all Iot Device with Device Provisioning service.

Thank you to all who give their important time to this thread.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The current version of IoTEdge runtime does not support DPS provisioning calls made by leaf devices with single level or multi-level nesting.

One workaround is to run forward proxy module in IoT Edge and configure leaf devices to use this proxy, this can be any containerized proxy server or you can modify the nginx base api-proxy-module (https://github.com/Azure/iotedge/tree/main/edge-modules/api-proxy-module) to act as forward proxy.

Comment: Thank You humblejay. I will look into this...